# A simple algebra

Tags: linear-algebra, gre-exam

[image]

What is the value of1 $0^0$ if I inserted $w=0$? If $0^0=1$ then the answer should be 4th and 5th option only.

Comment: 3rd is also an answer as $w^4 = (w^2)^2 > 0$

Comment: @user88595 If $w = 0$ it's not.

Comment: sorry got confused with non-positive and negative numbers, indeed.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you are correct. Usually
$$0^0 := 1$$
(note, this is a common definition, $0^0$ is also sometimes defined as $0$ or *undefined*, but that's rather uncommon)

Your additional task has these solutions in case you want to check:
$$w \in (-\infty, 0] \Rightarrow
\begin{align*}
-3w & \in [0, \infty) \\
2w + 10 & \in (-\infty, 10] \\
w^4 & \in [0, \infty) \\
w^0 & \in \{1\} \\
-w + 0.5 & \in [0.5, \infty)
\end{align*}$$

Comment: then what will be the choice for option 4?

Comment: @mathphy I'd say yes, but the question is somewhat ill-posed so your teacher or whoever may tell you otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

There's a [wikipedia entry](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/0_to_the_power_of_0#Zero_to_the_power_of_zero) on this. It basically says that depending on your angle of attack (how would you *define* $0^0$), it's probably either $1$ or undefined.

Comment: then what will be the choice for option 4?

Comment: @mathphy I think I'm saying it's a definite maybe, depending on your textbook and teacher. Seing that it says "_must_ be positive", you can be meta about it and say "$0^0$ doesn't _have_ to be positive", but in the end, it's up to whoever's grading this problem, and you probably know that person better than I do.

Comment: Authur it is a General gre Quantative  question. Can you say that which one they will take?

Comment: At high school level I'd go for yes. Even though a GRE is made with undergraduated in mind, it's not made specifically with _math_ undergrads in mind. So I'd say yes. But I cannot know for certain what the intended answer is.